# Drawing an irregular shape with a single loop

Tags: optimization

Lately I've been working on a problem where the program is to "draw" (using ASCII spaces and asterisks) three downward pointing and two upward pointing triangles with variable `height` which changes their height according to the user's wish so that they form the shapes of:

```
*****************************
 *******   *******   *******
  *****     *****     *****
   ***   *   ***   *   ***
    *   ***   *   ***   *
       *****     *****
      *******   *******
     *******************
(when user selects the height variable = 5)
```

and:

```
*****************************************  
 ***********   ***********   ***********
  *********     *********     *********  
   *******   *   *******   *   *******
    *****   ***   *****   ***   ***** 
     ***   *****   ***   *****   ***
      *   *******   *   *******   *
         *********     *********
        ***********   ***********
       ****************************
(when user selects the height variable = 7)
```

and so on.

I did solve the problem cause the brute force approach is pretty straightforward but I'm conscious of how poorly optimized that is. What I did was to divide it into three sections: three first rows, the center and three last rows. Then, we draw 6*`height`-1 asterisks in the first row, we print one space in the second row and then loop three times with the pairs ((3*`height`-3 asterisks), (3 spaces)) in the second row, three spaces and slightly modified pairs in the third row, then a changed approach (because we have to take the upward triangles into account now as well) for the center and so on and so forth. It works well but it's lots and lots of loops, to cut a long story short.

Today, when talking about the problem in class, my solution was accepted but the prof mentioned that all of this could be done with a single loop. It just got me thinking because I can't quite think of any method which would draw such an irregular shape with nothing but a single loop. Doesn't look like this could be done by simply printing "*" when some coordinate equality is fulfilled because there doesn't seem to be one here. Could you please help me with this? Is there really something which could draw it with a single loop?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
3 times
   top row
height - 3 times
   center row
3 times
   bottom row
```

you can do

```
height + 3 times
  if 3 top rows
    top row
  else if 3 bottom rows
    bottom row
  else
    center row
```

Comment: Yep, of course this would optimize the code but it's still not one loop since invoking any of the procedures (be it for top, bottom or center row) would involve another loop for any of the parts.